# MFC serialize C++

Tags: c++, serialization, mfc

I'm trying to serialize a listbox in MFC.

I used this code :

```
CFileDialog fileDlg(FALSE, _T(".txt"), NULL, 0, _T("Text File (.txt)|*.txt|")
        _T("All files (*.*)|*.*||"));

    if (fileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        const int numItems = m_listBox.GetCount();
        CString itemText;
        CStdioFile file;

        if (file.Open(fileDlg.GetFileName(), CStdioFile::modeCreate | CStdioFile::modeWrite))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
            {
                m_listBox.GetText(i, itemText);
                file.WriteString(itemText);
                file.WriteString(_T("\n"));
            }

            file.Close();
        }
```

But the saved file is always empty.
I tried a lot of versions of functions that save from listbox to text file but it didn't work.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run the shown code step by step, one line at a time, and inspect the values of all variables at each step, what did you see?

Comment: I cant run with debugger step by step in MFC project (breakpoint or f11 just "drop" me in run time)

Comment: You'll need to figure out how to debug the shown code. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer. Before asking questions on Stackoverflow everyone is required to try to debug their own code, and include their observations in their question.

Comment: You could use the brute-force "printf" method for debugging, if you don't have a useful debugger. That would be to fire off an `AfxMessageBox()` call to display things. For starters, I'd check that the `numItems` value is not 0. I doubt the problem is with the mechanics of writing the file [which is what you showed us] but with the `m_listBox` code, which you have not showed us.

Comment: Visual Studio has first class debugging. I've been doing it for over 20 years and it just works, (most of the time :) Set a break point at your first `if` and then F10 through your code.

Comment: A likely cause of you not being able to step debug is lack of symbols. You can got to Options > Debug, click Load All Symbols or something similar to get them all on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are using `CFileDialog::GetFileName`. Is that intentional? That will only pass in the file **name**.

I would use [`CFileDialog::GetPathName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class?view=msvc-160#getpathname) which returns the **full path** to the file.

And you should be using a debugger (compile in debug mode) so you can walk your code.

The [`CStdioFile::Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstdiofile-class?view=msvc-160#open) method can also be passed a pointer to an exception object. Have a look at the help.